# Parameters supplied for object Foo which is not a function mssql_query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert a record using the following SQL command

```
  INSERT INTO my_table (foo, bar) VALUES ('test1','test2')
```

however I seem to be running into the following error:

```
   Command execution failed: Parameters supplied for object 'my_table' which is not a function. If the parameters are intended as a table hint, a WITH keyword is required.
```

It executes just fine in the SQL Manager without any hickups however I cannot get it to excecute in mssql_query. Any ideas on why its preventing the record insert? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try protecting the table name with back-ticks: `INSERT INTO \`my_table\` (foo, bar) ...`

Comment: Hmmm, this is very odd I get "Command execution failed: Incorrect syntax near '`'."...

Comment: It's mssql, not mysql. Use surround your table name like this: [my_table].

Comment: Unfortunately, same problem :(

Comment: For some reason it keeps thinking im calling an SQL function which I am not... not sure why its doing that!

Comment: Well, that was stupid of me. I solved the issue, was using a variable to apply the table name and instead of "table" I had "tables". Sigh, thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @user1260028 I would suggest answering your own question and marking it answered. It will close this off and be a help to others in the same spot of bother in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error like this, it is most probable that you have a query string of something like:

```
 INSERT INTO table_name() VALUES...
```

as a result, SQL thinks you are trying to access a function

Answer (score 0):

Quite possible that there is some function with the same name as your table name. So the SQL tries to call that function, but there is a mismatch of parameter number etc..